# Django Rest Framework Overlaying Api Root

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to create a browsable API on url level of `/api`.

Browsable API is working for `/api/v1` and `/schema` separately well, when I address the url explicitly.
But I would like to create a browsable API a level above to browse to `/v1` and `/schema` directly.

This is my setup:

`django_project/config/urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views


from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse


urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include('my_api_app.router'), name="api"),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

`django_project/my_api_app/router.py`

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from rest_framework.schemas import get_schema_view

from .v1.router import router as v1_router

urlpatterns = [
    path('schema', get_schema_view(
          title="Python API",
          description="API for all things",
          version="1.0.0",
          public=True
    ), name='openapi-schema'),
    path('v1/', include(v1_router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
]
```

`django_project/my_api_app/v1/router.py`

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers

from . import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'testtable', views.TestTableViewSet)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a path to solve it.
The solution was to define an `api_root` in `my_api_app.v1.router`.

`django_project/config/urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views


from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse


urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include('my_api_app.router'), name="api"),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

`django_project/my_api_app/router.py`

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from rest_framework.schemas import get_schema_view
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse

from .v1.router import urlpatterns as v1_router

@api_view(['GET'])
def api_root(request, format=None):
    return Response({   
        'v1': reverse('v1_api', request=request, format=format),
    })

urlpatterns = [
    path('', api_root),
    path('v1/', include(v1_router), name="v1"),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
]
```

`django_project/my_api_app/v1/router.py`

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.urls import re_path as url
from rest_framework import routers
from rest_framework.schemas import get_schema_view
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse

from . import views

@api_view(['GET'])
def api_root(request, format=None):
    return Response({   
        'testtable': reverse('testtable-list', request=request, format=format),
        'shoppinglists': reverse('shoppinglists', request=request, format=format),
    })

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'testtable', views.TestTableViewSet, basename='testtable')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', api_root, name='v1_api'),
    path('shoppinglists/', views.RESTforCart.as_view(), name='shoppinglists'),
]

urlpatterns += router.urls
```